# PostgreSQL - Query keyword patterns in columns in table

Tags: sql, postgresql, design-patterns, substring

we all know in SQL we can query a column (lets say, column "breeds") for a certain word like "dog" via a query like this:

```
select breeds
from myStackOverflowDBTable
where breeds = 'dog'
```

However, say I had many more columns with much more data, say millions of records, and I did not want to find a word, but rather the most common keyword pattern or wildcard expression, a query like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM myStackOverflowDBTable
WHERE address LIKE '%alb%'"
```

Is there an efficient way to find these 'patterns' inside the columns using SQL? I need to find the most common substring so-to-speak, per the query above, say the wildcard string "alb" appeared the most in a "location" column that had words like Albany, Albuquerque, Alabama, obviously querying the words directly would yield 0 results but querying on that wildcard keyword pattern would yield many, but **I want to find the most repeating or most frequent wildcard/keyword pattern/regex expression/substring (however you want to define it) for a given column** - is there an easy way to do this without querying a million test queries and doing it manually???

Comment: Do you have a specified list of patterns? Or do you want to compute a pattern by the values you find in the column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you want to find three character patterns, you *could* extract all 3-character patterns, aggregate and count:

```
select substr(t.address, gs.i, 3) as ngram_3, count(*)
from t cross join lateral
     generate_series(1, length(address) - 3, 1) gs(i)
group by ngram_3
order by count(*) desc
limit 100;
```

Comment: Thank you. I will use this as a basis to test and experiment with different patterns of queries, thank you again!